# How Actions stored for Undo Redo in Professional Drawing App like Photoshop?

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, heap-memory, memory-efficient

I am making a drawing app and I have implemented the undo redo function successfully. But now I want to store the image in each action to heap memory but it is getting crash with `OutOfMemory`.

So I need some clarification from professional apps. How professional apps store the actions when drawing?

Comment: It can be implemented some various ways, but, for example, you don't save the whole image, but rather a list of "actions" that have been applied to the image. For example "red brush stroke from pixel1 to pixel2"

Answer (score 1):

What you are searching for the "Command Design Pattern".

refer to [What is the Action Design Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380724/what-is-the-action-design-pattern)

or https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command

or more generally: [Google it](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=Command%20Design%20Pattern&oq=Command%20Design%20Pattern&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i7i30k1l5j0j0i7i30k1j0j0i20k1.4016.4901.0.5179.8.7.0.0.0.0.208.751.0j2j2.4.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..6.2.362.le7URsLL_2Y)

The Command Object should contain data about the Action performed,

In some cases, you will need additional data for the Undo operation (e.g. when painting a Red square over a bunch of pixels, you need to save those pixels (of the same layer only)  this would request you to perform different thing per each operation, some would require the entire image, some a specific layer, and some can go without saving anything (e.g. new Layer).

Comment: This doesn't really answer how the image states are saved

Comment: the command object can Refer to a State of the image, store the type of action that was made to it, or even what data is needed for an UNDO (such as the block that was Covered by painting over it or such.)